# I cannot set inputProps as numeric type for MuiOtpInput from Mui OTP Input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-otp-input

I am attempting to use the `inputProps` prop with the `MuiOtpInput` component from `mui-one-time-password-input`. I have set the `inputMode` attribute to `"numeric"` for each input field, aiming to display the numeric keyboard on mobile devices.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
<MuiOtpInput 
  value={otp} 
  onChange={handleChange}         
  inputProps={[    { inputMode: 'numeric' },    { inputMode: 'numeric' },    { inputMode: 'numeric' },    { inputMode: 'numeric' },  ]}
/>
```

Here also my `handleChange` function:

```
  const handleChange = async (newValue) => {
    setOTP(newValue);
    console.log(newValue);

    if ((/^[0-9]{4}$/).test(newValue)) {
      console.log("submitting...");
      try {
        const { idToken, refreshToken } = await authentication.answerCustomChallenge(`${newValue}`)
        console.log("submitted!!");
        setAuth(true);
        const redirectURL = `${localStorage.getItem('redirectURL')}?idToken=${idToken.getJwtToken()}&refreshToken=${refreshToken.getToken()}`;
        localStorage.removeItem('redirectURL')
        window.location = redirectURL;
      } catch (err) {
        toast('Please enter the right code.');
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to be working as expected. I would appreciate any advice or guidance on how to achieve the desired behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: If you would like to use MuiOtpInput package and enforce full numerical rule. You can check out the working solution from here: https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-otp-input/issues/32.

Answer (score 0):

The `MuiOtpInput` package does have a way to validate the OTP characters while entering, and that can be used to make it numeric only.

It has a prop with name `validateChar` which takes a function for validation of each character entered.

Here is the code for the same:

```
<MuiOtpInput 
  value={otp} 
  onChange={handleChange}         
  validateChar={(val) => !isNaN(val)}
/>
```

Comment: @ShahryarFaraji `mui-one-time-password-input` package is much lighter than the `react-opt-input` and has lesser bugs known at hand.

Please upvote and accept my answer. Let me know in case something is off.

Comment: Your snippet still won't solve the numerical issue I raised. However, I'm glad to inform you that this issue has been resolved. You can check out the solution here: https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-otp-input/issues/32.

Comment: @ShahryarFaraji Actually I had tested the code on the playground linked on the official website. Similar code could be found here: https://viclafouch.github.io/mui-otp-input/docs/api-reference/#validatechar

Answer (score 0):

This configuration sets the input type to `number`, allowing only numeric input, and defines input properties specifying that only digits are allowed (0-9) using the `pattern` attribute.

This works for me incase of `MuiOtpInput`:

```
TextFieldsProps={{
            type: 'number',
            inputProps: {
              inputMode: 'numeric',
              pattern: '[0-9]*',
            },
          }}
```